# SonarQube line length rule uses 8 character tabs. Is there config for tab size?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've noticed recently that the SonarQube rule for Line Length Squid:S00103 expands tab characters as 8 spaces. Is there a configuration to change this? Our Eclipse formatter treats tab characters as 4 spaces and I want the rule to match, rather than having to remove tabs from all files. With current operation I get violations for files that look fine in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab characters are counted as single characters by the rule S00103 of the SonarQube Java Analyzer, as it can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Consequently, this rule should not raise such issues. The only way the rule will raise issue will come from the opposite situation, when extra spaces are added by the user as prefix of the lines to "align" correctly with lines prefixed with tabs.

Now, note that it is not possible to configure the tab size using the SonarQube platform, the effective width being controlled by browser/os.

Comment: You are correct. My fault. I have a "modern" profile I use on my own machine in which I am bringing the old deprecated rules up to date. The project profile on the common server is still running with the old puppycrawl rule, and it counts the tabs as 8 spaces. I did a test line with three tabs and puppycrawl reported 175 characters where squid reported 154. Nice fix. I will rush that rule upgrade into production.